# How does a dry shampoo work?

Tags: acid-base, water, solubility, van-der-waals-behavior, soap

From my chemistry knowledge, I know that soaps are made from fatty acids and some sort of base and this reaction also gives us $\ce{H_2O}$ so the grease in hair dissolves and gets washed away in water. What I don't understand is how dry shampoos can have a cleaning effect on dirt or grease and how they work.

Comment: They work on the assumption that grease and oils stick more tightly to the cleaner flakes than to hair. It's the same as using adhesive tape to remove label stickum left on a container. Oh, and the cleaner likely tries to cover any bad odor with an overpowering "perfume".